# rails link_to with raw and translation i18n tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am trying to make a button on my rails 6 app, including a fontawesome icon inside of it and the name of the button translate.

This is my button so far:

```
<%= link_to raw('<i class="fas fa-paint-roller"></i>'), request.params.merge(category: "3"), class: "button is-rounded" %>
```

I want to include in it:

```
  <%= t "services.title" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
  <%= link_to your_url_path, class: "button is-rounded" do %>
    <i class="fas fa-paint-roller"></i> <%= t "services.title" %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: I tried already this solution, but it make new trouble in my app with the autocomplete function i am using

Comment: actually i worked thanks, my mistake, here is the final code:

 <%= link_to request.params.merge(category: "3"), class: "button is-rounded" do %>   
 <i class="fas fa-paint-roller"></i><%= t "services.title" %>
<% end %>